# Php array search optimization

Tags: php, arrays, optimization

Here is the task.
I need to recognize whether a string contains some town name.
Another words - a recognition of a town from some text.

As input i have text to search against AND geocode.
Depending on geocode list of towns are loaded from db.

Now, current implementations is i loop over list of those towns and try to match it with the use of short circuit evaluation. 
Like:

```
if (stripos($text, $currentTown) !== false && 
    preg_match("#\b$currentTown\b#i", $text)) {
    // add town to recognized list
}
```

And the problem is i have e.g. list of towns for UK (which is about 40 000) the loop will take "quite a while".

So my question is how do i optimize the recognition time.
Maybe there is some advanced search in the array?

Any ideas are welcome.

Thanks.

Comment: This is similar to the DNA sequence search problem.

Comment: and what would be the solution ?

Comment: Wouldn't sql LIKE be faster than your php snippet ?

Comment: As you may be thinking, an array with 40,000 elements might not be the best way to go. I second the suggestion to go with a DB or service solution

Comment: honestly saying i haven't thought about this solution. i will have to it thoroughly. the rlike needs to be used instead of like in order to match a town name in between word boundaries though

Comment: Read up on the MySQL FULLTEXT algo.  Essentially you maintain a hash of all words that are in town names, chop the string into words and lookup each word against the hash.  You'll need to do a second pass to whittle down putative matches against you town list (e.g. a string with _East_ in it will generate quite few hits).

Answer (score 0):

Although my best bet instantly was to use ['MySQL full text search'](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman//5.5/en/fulltext-boolean.html) I will attempt to solve your problem. I will try to start with 'best results'.

1. Keep all your town data in lowercase (or atleast where you search in) and use `$text = strtolower($text);` before searching: so you can use `strpos` Case sensitive search > insensitive search
2. Why bother with preg_match(); as your doing 99% the same thing with stripos. You can skip it.
3. Perhaps add small checks like if strlen($text) < 4 don't even try to search as it gives horrible results.
4. Order your data by length (this is super expensive so do this once and store it) and skip the currentTowns that are shorter than the input.
5. Order your data alphabetical and only go through the part which matches the first letter (or first + second even)
6. Possibly, cache results / searches. Then you only have to search through your cache if it can find some row (but ye cache miss hurts)
7. If you have large data sets, maybe the [PHP Iterator class](http://php.net/manual/en/class.iterator.php) can help out. It could speed up the process of going over each record.